# XPath expression to select children

Tags: c#, xpath

Currently I have the following code to get the children of a given node with a specific local-name:

```
node.XPathSelectElements("//*[local-name()='param']");
```

But this gives me all the `param` nodes in the document and I just want the children of `node`.

What I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add leading `.` to tell that the XPath is relative to current `node` element :

```
node.XPathSelectElements(".//*[local-name()='param']");
```

And replace double `/` with single if you really meant *children* instead of *descendants* :

```
node.XPathSelectElements("./*[local-name()='param']");
```